# Minecraft Plugin Help (Spigot)

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, minecraft

Need help on minecraft spigot plugin.

[this is the layout (or build path if you want to call it that)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wu9T.png)

Here is the code for the main file (main.java)

```
package com.angosa;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import com.angosa.listener.Listeners;



public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override

    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Listeners(), this);
        
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the listeners.java (which is in the listener package)

```
package com.angosa.listener;
import org.bukkit.entity.Creeper;

import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.CreatureSpawnEvent;

public class Listeners implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public void creatureSpawn(CreatureSpawnEvent event) {
        if(event.getEntityType() == EntityType.CREEPER) {
            
            Creeper creeper = (Creeper) event.getEntity();
            
            creeper.setPowered(true);
            creeper.setHealth(100);
            creeper.setExplosionRadius(200);
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

and then here is the yml file

```
main: com.angosa.Main
name: OPCreeper
version: 1.0
author: Claim
```

also, in case that the version is wrong, here's what it looks like when I upload it onto a server.

```
[18:06:11 ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins/OPCreeper.jar' in folder 'plugins'
```

org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: Invalid plugin.yml
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:170) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:144) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:383) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:185) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:808) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning for the next token
found character '\t(TAB)' that cannot start any token. (Do not use \t(TAB) for indentation)
in 'reader', line 7, column 1:

```
^

at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:419) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:227) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingKey.produce(ParserImpl.java:558) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:148) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:235) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:162) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getNode(Composer.java:95) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:119) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:150) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:472) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:411) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile.<init>(PluginDescriptionFile.java:252) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:165) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
... 6 more
```

Comment: Did you read these parts of your log? `Do not use \t(TAB) for indentation` ``Cannot find main class `com.angosa.Main.OPCreeper'``

Comment: It looks like you need to change `main: com.angosa.Main.OPCreeper` to `main: com.angosa.Main`

Answer (score 5):

I see the problem in the first console line:

```
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: Invalid plugin.yml
```

And at the end you can see:

```
 (Do not use \t(TAB) for indentation)
```

In my opinion, you just have to:

1. Clear your plugin.yml file and fill it again properly (Without using TAB key)
2. Put your plugin.yml file into your src folder
3. Save before to export*

*For me, it looks like your "main" value in the plugin.yml file was:

```
main: com.angosa.Main.OPCreeper
```

but as you send in this thread, the proper value is:

```
com.angosa.Main
```

so don't forget saving before to export your plugin, i'm not sure at all but it may be the problem.*

To show you, there is an exemple of plugin i'm working in :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/55JVe.png : Package Explorer & plugin.yml
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiWpN.png : Main class

*(OrbeDisplay.java = Main.java in this case)*

If it doesn't works after this, I will search for another solution, so keep me posted.

Sorry for my bad English, I come from France and I just started to learn.

Answer (score 1):

It's great that you are starting with spigot development!

The problem with your plugin is that you are using the wrong format in your plugin.yml file. It seems that on line 7 you are using a TAB instead of a space. I suggest looking at this help page https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/plugin-yml/ for help on finding the correct format!

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Tabs in YAML Files like plugin.yml
use Spaces instead

Comment: How much that it use spaces instead of tab it true about YAML sad